# How can I access childViewControllers in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller

I used containerView in static table cell on StoryBoard.

```
self.TableViewCell.childViewControllers[0];
self.ContentView.childViewControllers[0];
self.childViewControllers[0];
```

These had nothing. I want not to use custom UIViewCell.

How can I access in TableViewController?

Comment: My guess is you don't have "child view controllers" in your cell, but rather "subviews"?

Comment: I used ContainerView in my table cell rightly.

Comment: Huh? What is 'self' in your code referring to?

Comment: 'self' means my TableViewController.

Comment: Once again, I highly doubt your cells/tableView have child "view controllers". What you probably think you're referring to are their subviews. Use subviews instead.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. There are no child view controllers in a table cell. What are you trying to access/do with your code?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry Mike:( It worked using subviews. I confused. Thank you.

Comment: I have a question now. "child view controllers" is one of subviews in UIView, isn't it?

Comment: No, childViewControllers is an array property of UIViewController, so it's not a view, and therefore cannot be a subview of anything.

Comment: I didn't know "Container View" properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController class you can just create array property that will keep references on childViewControllers.
If you add childViewController programmatically, you can just add reference to array in code.
If you use embed segue in storyboard, you can get childViewController by getting destinationViewController of segue in prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EmbedSegue"]) {
        UIViewController *childViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [self.childViewControllers addObject:childViewController];
    }
}
```